# tab bar view controller is black and tabs disappear when pressed

Tags: swift3, uitabbarcontroller

In My storyboard, I have tab bar controller with three tableview controllers, each wrapped in a separate navigation controller and hooked to tab view controller. 
When the code runs initially the tab bar shows up with all tabs, but view controller display is black. Once a press a tab the appropriate controller shows up, but all tabs including the one I pressed disappear. If I continue to press the tab bar with approximate locations of the tabs then each controller comes up.  But tab bar is empty. I tried setting tabbar isHidden to false, but no luck.
Also why is the first time the controller display is black. How can I fix this?

Code:

```
extension ViewTabBarController: UITabBarControllerDelegate {
func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, didSelect viewController: UIViewController) {
        let myVC1 = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "EVC") as! TableViewController1
        myVC.selectedTab = self.selectedTab

        let myVC2 = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PVC") as! TableViewController2

        let myVC3= UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TVC") as! TableViewController3

    let controllers = [myVC1, myVC2, myVC3,]

        self.viewControllers = controllers.map { UINavigationController(rootViewController: $0)}
    }
}
class ViewTabBarController: UITabBarController {
    var selectedTab:Int = 0
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.delegate = sell
    }
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        self.tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = false
    }
    override func tabBar(_ tabBar: UITabBar, didSelect item: UITabBarItem) {
        self.selectedTab = (tabBar.items?.index(of: item))!
        print (self.selectedTab)

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this it may helps you.

Is your storyboard in this way??
[image]

If yes then may the tabController as initial viewController.
Like [image]